# finding the total of click for same date in list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I want to find the total click for each date. I have tried many methods but couldn't get an appropriate one. below I will write down the target list of dictionaries

```
data = [{"click":"3","time":"2020-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"6","time":"2020-08-22T10:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"7","time":"2020-08-22T11:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"8","time":"2020-08-22T12:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"29","time":"2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"13","time":"2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Here there in this data list,for 2020-08-22 date there are 3 dict with different click value. so i want total click for 2020-08-22 date which is 21.

please help me to get result like this,

```
data = [{"click":"3","time":"2020-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"21","time":"2020-08-22T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"29","time":"2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"click":"13","time":"2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Thank you for your consideration and forthcoming response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) split the date by `T` & use date component to groupby & sum the values.

```
from itertools import groupby

print([
    {"time": k + "T00:00:00.000Z", "click": sum(int(vv['click']) for vv in v)}
    for k, v in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['time'].split("T")[0])
])
```

---

```
[{'time': '2020-08-21T00:00:00.000Z', 'click': 3}, ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

below

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{"click": "3", "time": "2020-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"},
        {"click": "6", "time": "2020-08-22T10:00:00.000Z"},
        {"click": "7", "time": "2020-08-22T11:00:00.000Z"},
        {"click": "8", "time": "2020-08-22T12:00:00.000Z"},
        {"click": "29", "time": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z"},
        {"click": "13", "time": "2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"}]

collected_clicks = defaultdict(int)
collected_clicks_lst = []
for entry in data:
    clicks = int(entry['click'])
    date = entry['time'][:10]
    collected_clicks[date] += clicks
for date,clicks in collected_clicks.items():
    collected_clicks_lst.append({'click': clicks, 'time': date + 'T00:00:00.000Z'})
print(collected_clicks_lst)
```

output

```
[{'click': 3, 'time': '2020-08-21T00:00:00.000Z'}, {'click': 21, 'time': '2020-08-22T00:00:00.000Z'}, {'click': 29, 'time': '2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z'}, {'click': 13, 'time': '2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply python :)

```
groupedData = {}
for oneSet in data:
    setDate = oneSet["time"].split("T")[0]
    if setDate not in groupedData:
       groupedData[setDate]= int(oneSet["click"])
    else:
       groupedData[setDate]+=int(oneSet["click"])

#Data grouped according to date
refinedData = [{"click":str(groupedData[key]),"time":key+"T00:00:00.000Z"}for key in groupedData]
```

Output

> [{'click': '3', 'time': '2020-08-21T00:00:00.000Z'},
> {'click': '21', 'time': '2020-08-22T00:00:00.000Z'},
> {'click': '29', 'time': '2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z'},
> {'click': '13', 'time': '2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z'}]

Comment: additional ``imports`` is to avoid re-inventing wheels (re-writting redudant code)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
total_click_dict = dict()

for d in data:
    # Find first occurrence of 'T' - it separates the date from the rest of the timestamp
    # i.e. 2020-08-22 <- T -> 11:00:00.000Z
    first_index_of_date_seperator = d['time'].find('T')
    # Fetching date
    date = d['time'][0:first_index_of_date_seperator]
    # If date not in dictionary
    if not date in total_click_dict:
        # Create a counter for date
        total_click_dict[date] = 0
    # Increase current date counter by amounts of clicks
    total_click_dict[date] += int(d['click'])

# {'2020-08-21': 3, '2020-08-22': 21, '2020-08-24': 29, '2020-08-25': 13}
print(total_click_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution returning required format

```
new_map = {}
result = []
for entry in data:
    time = entry.get('time').split('T')[0]
    click = int(entry.get('click'))
    if time+"T00:00:00.000Z" not in new_map:
        new_map[time+"T00:00:00.000Z"] = click
    else:
        new_map[time+"T00:00:00.000Z"] += click
for entry in new_map:
    result.append({"click":str(new_map.get(entry)), "time":entry})
```